# Auto Power on Android when the charger is Connected

Tags: android

I'm Developing an Android Application where it's constantly required to keep the App up an running at all time. with the phone connected to a power outlet at all time, Is it possible that if the phone's battery died to Auto-start up the app with no user intervention . ****i.e to power up the phone automatically without hitting any power button and start up android since charger is connected. **** 
then start up my app with android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission

PS: I have tried android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED but it only works if the phone is already powered up.

Comment: If the device is powered off, what do you expect to be able to send you the notification that power was connected? There's nothing running to do so, and until the power button is pressed to turn the device back on nothing *can* be running. You question is basically "how can I programmatically detect the charger was connected without running a program?", which of course makes no sense.

Comment: I know it kinda makes no sense but how would you expect your android phone to run the alarm while the phone is off ?

Comment: There's a difference between "sleeping" and "powered down". It's kind of like a person taking a nap instead of being in a coma. Your question said "powered off". IF it's powered off, it's off. Alarms on my phone don't work if it's totally powered down; they work fine when it's just sleeping.

Comment: ok then, How's the system gets notified when sleepin ?!

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly same requirement as yours.

Can we plan a solution like this:

The Android device is always connected to charger's output.
Charger's power supply is connected to a custom made hardware device which controls power supply to charger.
This hardware device puts charger off until battery is getting low. i.e. 20% remaining.
Once battery is less than 20%, that device automatically switch on the charger.
The "custom made hardware" gets it input from android device itself via USB/WiFi/Bluetooth.

Just a thought. May not be practically possible.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Note that this works fine on iphone, if you connect the charger, it boots up. We need to find a bootloader that when charger is connected, it boots the phone up.

Comment: we've done that exactly through the bluetooth API since UBS is not available for all platforms

Answer (score 1):

No way doing it if you do not root your device and add reboot scripts to the programs running to show battery charging pictures when device is turned off and charging.[for Samsung s2 here is an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make an additional app that waits for the BOOT_COMPLETED with its BroadcastReceiver and then check wether the power is connected and start as a new Intent your application?

Just a quick thought..

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i'm actually after is that if your phone is turned off, Is it possible to power it up once the charger is connected without hitting any buttons, Is it possible for the android system to fire/broadcast any kinda of an event/Intent if the phone is turned off in response to any sort of plugins like the charger?!..

Comment: I can only speak for my HTC Sensation which boots automatically if it was powered off and charger is connected.
But you have to reenter PIN to have the phone work properly, without PIN question it stays in the lockscreen. Anyhow, it then works just like you turned it on yourself. Maybe I just did not understand your question well..

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.

The solution that i will to implement:

1.- get out two(here is my doubt, ¿what two wires?, because i see three, i will use my multimeter for see continuity between wires when i push the button) wires from the power button phone.(when you push that button, it just connect two poles like a switch).

2.- When you have the two wires, so, we build a little circuit with a timer like a 555(integrated circuit). The purpose of the circuit will connect the two wires(from power button phone) by a 5 seconds period every 15minutes.

Obviously this circuit will be running always.